# JSON payload problems, javascript encoding

Tags: javascript, utf-8, iso-8859-1, latin1

I have read a bunch of different StackOverflow answers and similar questions but none of them have been any help.

I am using Javascript to make an ajax request to get some data in json form.

I am receving json data such as the following:

`\u0093title\u0094`

Now I believe json is delivered in utf-8 by default, however these characters `\u0093`and `\u0094` I believe are latin1 control characters meant to represent open and close speech marks.

The issue is when I make the GET with Javascript, the response ends up being something like:

`Â“titleÂ”`

I have tried doing `encodeURIComponent( data.body ))` and it produces the same result

This is extremely annoying, has anyone else encountered these issues before?

EDIT:

Imagine the following raw JSON data, this is what I am going to retrieve:

`\u0093title\u0094`

So for example, I run the following piece of jQuery/Javascript to get the above JSON data

```
                $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "myurl",
                  success: function(data){
                     console.log(data.body);
                  }
                });
```

The following is printed to the console (which looks fine, except it is omitting the control characters):

`title`

And then I encode and decode it, which should cancel out and change nothing:

`console.log(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent( data.body )))`

Except this ends up printing the following:

`Â“titleÂ”`

Where it has picked up those extra `Â` characters as well as the `“` and `”`, despite these not showing up in the console before the encode/decode step

Comment: You print `Â“titleÂ”` in your HTML yes?

Comment: Essentially yes, or if I print it to the debug console it also comes out like that

Comment: Have you set the charset to utf8? `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Won't help, I am injecting the scripts after the page had loaded and rendered

Comment: `U+0093` and `U+0094` are non-printable characters. Are you sure you don't mean curved quotes?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Code Points `U+0093` and `U+0094` are not curved quotes, they are control characters for something else... (which to be quite honest, I have no idea). Curved Quotes code points are `U+201C` for `“` and `U+201D` for `”`. You still have another problem:

This pretty much looks like an example of incorrect decoding format. The program which is decoding the character saw: `C2 93`, the hex value of unicode point `0093`. He's not assuming it's UTF-8 or he would have make a translation to unicode point `0093`. Instead, it's using Windows Code Page-1252. Which makes: `C2` into `Â`, `93` into `“` and `94` into `”`.

I could only think of 2 reasons why is it doing that but they all involve your browser. Is not really a problem with Javascript not using UTF-8, because this works:

```js
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '\u201CHello\u201D';
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

The problem could be the HTTP response, your browser is reading the HTTP response as Windows Code Page-1252. The other thing it could be is because your browser is presenting data incorrectly (which now that i think of it, doesn't make much sense).

Try setting up the Content-Type of your HTTP response by sending this HTTP header:

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

And I insist that you put the:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

To your document.

Comment: Thank you for the long reply. I have updated my question to better reflect the nature of my question and hopefully give a better idea to what is happening - as I have this issue without even inserting anything into any HTML elements